# How to read the errno of a child process created by system() function?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am using the following code

```
system("gcc -c main.c -o main.o");
system("gcc -c add.c -o add.o");
system("gcc  main.o add.o -o Output.exe");
```

This code generally executes all the statements all the time . I want to stop the execution if there is any error in the code i.e if there is an error in main.c then the below two statements should not be executed .
and if add.c has a error then the third should not execute.
One advice I found is to use the errno values set by the function so how to do that ?
We know that system() creates a child using fork() as per the man page
So i want to read the errno value from the child !

Comment: You can't read `errno`. But you can check what the command passes to the `exit` function (or returns from its `main` function). [Read the `system` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `make`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg
I mean passing exit(errno)
and collecting it with wait(&status)

Comment: @dbush I am writing a code to implement make utility so is the reason

Comment: You still can't. What build utilities is checking is the exit code of the program.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But he said he's using `errno` as the exit code, so he's already solved that part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

System returns the command's exit status. So you can do:

```
error = system("gcc -c main.c -o main.o");
if (error) {
    // report error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The helpful documentation found in [`man system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) tells you what the function returns:

> If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the termination status of the child shell used to execute command.  (The termination status of a shell is the termination status of the last command it executes.)

You should *always* check the return values of standard library functions, particularly if you find yourself wondering if they worked.

Comment: The termination status of the shell is the termination status of the last command for common shells, but that's only a convention, you can write a shell that doesn't follow the convention and then you have to cope with that.